# Swift 3: Enlarging images when selected in CollectionView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uicollectionview

Good day, I have only seen examples of this in Objective-C or Swift 2 but not yet in Swift 3 running Xcode 8. My situation is that I have a collection view with a set of images and I want them to be enlarged when the user taps on them. Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!


var images = ["catPic1.jpg", "catPic2.jpg", "catPic3.jpg"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        collectionView.delegate = self

        collectionView.dataSource = self

    } // end of view did load

 public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return images.count
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell" , for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        cell.myImage.image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row])


        return cell

    }
```

By the way, I have the collection view cell code in another swift class. Here's the code:

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var myImage: UIImageView!
}
```

All the images are showing correctly, I just need them to somehow enlarge when the user selects them. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use another `UIImageView` to view fullscreen your image

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row]))
    imageView.frame = self.view.frame
    imageView.backgroundColor = .black
    imageView.contentMode = .top
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissFullscreenImage))
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
}

// Use to back from full mode
func dismissFullscreenImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. Only thing is that it does not center the image in the zoomed view (when it brings it fullscreen). Some of the images appear to be too close or not completely shown. @Luan Tran

Comment: Hi. I'm glad to help you. You can change `contentMode` for center the image. Change to `imageView.contentMode = .center` or `imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. @Luan Tran

Comment: try with

                  self.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleToFill